# Service to tracking strange behavior (not crash) on an iOS app

Tags: ios, web-services, debugging

Currently, I use Crashlytics to track crashes on my iOS app.

But, I'm looking for a solution which permits to send an event from the iOS app to a dashboard when a condition is not verified.

For exemple:

```
if theEarthIsRound
{
    // Everything is ok
}
else
{
    // Oh my god WTF !
}
```

In the `else` condition, the app doesn't crash and I display an error message to the user to tell that something is wrong with the app and he should restart it.

But unfortunately, I will never have a notification that this message has been displayed to the user, thus I will never be notify that there is a bug in the app even if it didn't crash.

So in the `else` condition, I would like to send a notification to a service which notify me that something is wrong in the user instance of my app.

Does anybody know a that does this?

Comment: ACRA can do this, but it is only for Android...